# Clients.All, Clients.Caller and Clients.Others throwing TypeLoadException

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I have a simple Typed Hub setup through an interface. I can successfully connect to the SignalR Hub.

```
namespace POC.WebSocket
{
    public class ApiResultHub : Hub<IApiResultHubClient>
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(user, message);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Clients.Caller.ReceiveMessage("newUser", $"{Context.ConnectionId}");
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try invoke a client side hub method it throws the following exception:
[image]

Here are my other class files:
Startup.cs

```
namespace POC.WebSocket
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44324", "https://localhost:44326")
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ApiResultHub>("/apiResult");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

IApiResultHubClient`T.cs

```
namespace POC.Common
{
    public interface IApiResultHubClient
    {
        Task ReceiveMessage(string user, string message);
        Task SendApiResponse<T>(ApiResult<T> data);
    }
}
```

Has anyone else seen this issue? I saw few similar issues with being able to connect to the hub itself. However, as mentioned I am able to successfully connect to the hub, just not able to resolve Clients.All, Clients.Caller or Clients.Others.

All libraries updated today:

.Net Core version 2.1.4
.Net SignalR Core version 1.0.3

**Edits:**
Found details of the exception:

> Method 'SendApiResponse' in type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.TypedClientBuilder.IApiResultHubClientImpl'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.TypedClientBuilder,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have
>   an implementation.